# jQuery DataTable Detail does not execute onclick href

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable, which when opening the detail, [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html), shows some information and also a link (href), this link has a call to a function of the controller, but clicking does not happen.

In the creation of my datatable I am using as search here in the forum, $ compile, to recognize the functions of the controller, the problem is that it does not even call this function.
I have already tried to change the function call by an "alert ('test')" and also did not execute

```
'<a ng-click="gerarDacte(' + d.documentoCodigo + ');" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-twitter mr5"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Gerar</a> ' +
```

Observe this line above

```
function table(dados) {
    $scope.listaDadosGrid = dados;
    console.log(dados);

    function format(d) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        var html =


            '<div class="demo-button3"> '+
            '<a ng-click="gerarDacte(' + d.documentoCodigo + ');" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-twitter mr5"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Gerar</a> ' +
            '<br>' +
            '</div> ';


        return html;
    };

    var selecionados = [];

    $(document).ready(function (data) {

        var table = $('#tableDocumentos').DataTable({

            aaData: dados,

            language: {
                url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json",
                decimal: ",",
                thousands: "."
            },
            deferRender: true,
            bAutoWidth: false,
            bProcessing: true,
            bDeferRender: true,

            createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
            },
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 0,
                searchable: false,
                orderable: false,
                checkboxes: {
                    selectRow: true
                },
            }],
            select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },


            sAjaxDataProp: "",
            bDestroy: true,
            order: [[2, "asc"]],
       });

        $('#tableDocumentos tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }

        });
}
```

function gerarDacte

```
$scope.gerarDacte = function (idDocumentoLogistico) {
    //go to...
}
```

I created an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jolask/ADukg/16214/)

Thank you

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: You almost certainly need to wrap that callback in `$scope.$applyAsync`

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad formatting. Aluan Haddad, I would have some example to use in this case, as I do not know how to use `$scope.$ApplyAsync` in calling a function. I do not know if it would be time to use it. Thank you

Comment: You need to `$compile` the content, there is hundreds of similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in small comment above, you should use `$compile` in order to bind the child row to `$scope` :

```
} else {
  // Open this row
  row.child(format(row.data()), 'no-padding').show();
  tr.addClass('shown');

  $compile(row.child()[0])($scope); //<-- HERE

  $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
}
```

You would also need to actually bind your *function* to the `$scope` :

```
$scope.gerarDacte = function(id){
   alert(id);
}
```

Now it works, updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16222/**

But why you want to bind the child row to `$scope` I cannot comprehend, seems a little bit overkill. You can bind a javascript / jQuery event listener to the button (or whatever) and access `$scope` from within that listener, you do not need to go all the way through angular. If you have two way binding to form elements or used more advanced directives it is OK, but a simple click is not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the help davidkonrad, worked perfectly. I'm starting to work with angularjs and jquery, I do not know which are still best practices, I saw some example of the same jquery I tried to do.